# Why does grunt not get installed via bower.js?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower, frontend

I am new to front end package managers.To install bower, we need npm in prerequisite and then bower takes charge of all the libraries on the client end. However to install grunt, I still need to install it via npm -

- npm install -g grunt-cli npm
- install grunt-contrib --save-dev
- npm install -g grunt

I did not understand why can not we install it via bower as in:

- bower install -g grunt-cli
- bower install grunt-contrib --save-dev
- bower install -g grunt

and manage the bower.json file insted of managing two different - **bower.json** and **package.json**?

Answer (score 1):

Bower itself server side dependency which is made using node and you pull it using npm and manage client side dependency by bower

[Bower](http://bower.io/) is a package management system for client-side programming unlike npm (node package manager ) which is for server side dependencies

npm runs through the command line and manages dependencies for an application server side as you know nodejs is not client side

so you bower for stuff like ... jquery , angular 
and npm for like ... gulp, grunt

Comment: Thanks Richerd. Please correct me if I am wrong, but are nt gulp,grunt for client side too?

Comment: @pank.bh92 no gulp and grunt are not for client side ... like they are in node_modules not in bower directroy